# How to get CLion ot show QString values in when debugging?

Tags: qt, clion

Seeing this blew my mind:

[image: CLion showing the type of variable in C++]

But it would be really awesome if it actually showed me the value inside it. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible yet - but upvote the request on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-605 to get this traction.

Answer (score 3):

I just added `var.toStdString()` in watchs.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use gdb command in console:

```
print ((wchar_t*)((char *)str.d + str.d->offset))
```

or just add watch in "Variables":

```
((wchar_t*)((char *)str.d + str.d->offset))
```

Another way is use [this project](https://github.com/Lekensteyn/qt5printers) to add Qt pretty printer.

Comment: wchar_t is 16 bits on Windows, but 32 bits everywhere else. So, no.

Answer (score 1):

From https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-605, the Clion ticket vadim-peretokin linked to in his answer.

On Windows... you can use natvis files with MSVC.

1. enable the setting  [Enable NatVis renderers for LLDB](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#msvc-debugger).
2. Add `qt5.natvis` or `qt6.natvis` to your source directory,

Download links for the natvis files can be found on https://wiki.qt.io/IDE_Debug_Helpers, but also below. You'll need to drop the `.xml` extension for the debugger to recongize and load the file.

- [qt5.natvis.xml](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/plain/QtMSBuild/QtMsBuild/qt5.natvis.xml)
- [qt6.natvis.xml](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-labs/vstools.git/plain/QtMSBuild/QtMsBuild/qt6.natvis.xml)